# How to Compare a String with a integer Postgres

Tags: string, postgresql, integer, compare

How can I compare an empty String with a Integer in Postgres ?

For Example:
Select * From xyz where anynumber = ''

Comment: And what do you intend the result to be?

Comment: '' should correspond to 0

Comment: Then say `where anynumber = '0'`.  :P  Empty strings have no numeric value.

Comment: kk. I'll try to describe my Problem. We've got an old Programm which works with Sybase Database. My Job is to Change the Database to Postgres. So i get a query From the Programm and Try to execute this. In Sybase it works fine but in postgres it doesnt work.

Comment: Bah.  Should have switched to SQL Server.  :)  They're actually related, IIRC.  But yeah...empty strings aren't ints.  You might be able to do something like `('0' || string)::int`, but i forget whether Postgres knows about octal literals.  If it does, that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

A numeric column can't be "blank", but it can be `null`. I think that's what you want:

Given that `anynumber` is nullable, ie

```
create table xyz (
    ...
    anynumber int,  -- ie not "NOT NULL"
    ...
)
```

You can test for null:

```
select * From xyz where anynumber is null
```

Comment: We've found antoher solution. Thank's everybody :)

Comment: And what was that solution?

Comment: @SimonLudwig this site is about sharing knowledge, not only solving developers troubles. You should share your solution answering yor own question.